# Putnam Question (Pigeonhole Principle on divisibility of sequences)

Tags: contest-math, divisibility, pigeonhole-principle

Problem (from page 338 of *Putnam and Beyond*):
Let $x_1 = x_2 = x_3= 1$ and $x_{n+3} = x_n + x_{n+1} x_{n+2}$ for all positive integers $n.$  Prove that for any positive integer $m$ there is an index $k$ such that $m$ divides $x_k$.

Solution:
We are allowed by the recurrence relation to set $x_0 = 0.$  We will prove that there is an index $k \leq{m^3}$ such that $x_k$ divided $m.$  Let $r_{t}$ be the remainder obtained by dividing $x_t$ by m for $t = 0,1,\ldots,m^3 + 2.$  Consider the triples ($r_0,r_1,r_2), (r_1,r_2,r_3),\ldots,(r_{m^3},r_{m^3 + 1},r_{m^3 + 2}).$  Since $r_t$ can take m values, the pigeonhole principle implies that at least two triples are equal...

Note: I don't quite understand the last part of the last line of the above paragraph.  How does the fact that $r_t$ can have $m$ values, imply that at least two triples are equal.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your continual alternation in and out of MathJax and your exclusion of "plus" signs and "equals" signs from within MathJax is not proper MathJax usage. See my edits to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The pigeonhole principle states that given $p$ pigeons in $h$ holes, if $p>h$, then at least one hole must have two pigeons in it, no matter how you go about your pigeon-stuffing.

The possible remainder-triples$\mod m$ are your holes. There are $m$ congruence classes $\mod m$. So a triple of remainders could take $m^3$ values.

The actual remainder-triples are your pigeons. Note that you can count them by counting the first index (from $0$ to $m^3$) = $m^3 + 1$.

$m^3 + 1 > m^3 \implies p > h \implies \exists h_i,p_a,p_b$ s.t. $p_a\to h_i\land p_b\to h_i$

Answer (score 0):

There are $m^3 + 1$ triples (these are your pigeons) and there exists $m^3$ different configurations for a given triple (these are your holes). By the pigeonhole principle, two triples must be equal.

Comment: I still don't see where the need to satisfy the k $\leq{m^3}$ comes from.  That ${m^3}$ term just seems kind of random.

Comment: Well, the proof surely isn't over yet. The justification for this $m^3$ term, and the fact that we are looking at triples, must appear in the next steps of the proof, surely.